# box-shadow css property, the effective way to produce drop shadow effect?

Tags: css

I've been researching on drop-shadow-effect technique for web design.
So, I would like to apply the technique to use implementing a top header bar for my website.

From my findings, the one that people out there use the most is box-shadow css property.
I'd like to know if this is the most effective yet simple way to achieve the desired outcome or not. any other options available for me to implement the same as well as their pros and cons?

any advice would be very much appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way is Photoshop :)

Otherwise, read on: http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

`box-shadow` is a CSS3 property, meaning it's not available in < IE9, and not natively available in most browsers, hence the proprietary prefixes:

Sample CSS code for IE drop shadow:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#000000',direction='120',strength='20');
```

CSS3 version:

```
element {
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    -o-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    -khtml-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only other option to the CSS3 box-shadow property is to use images. CSS3 box shadows are easier to apply and require less page weight (kb) to use. However, not all browsers will support CSS3 box-shadows.

If using the box-shadow property be certain to set all the various properties for different browsers.

```
box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #000;
-o-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #000;
-khtml-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #000;
```

Comment: The `box-shadow` should be last, with vendor specifics before it.